# Converting a pandas dataframe into a torch Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch, transformer-model, torchaudio

I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

| path | sentence | speech | input_values | labels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| audio1.mp3 | This is the first audio | [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ..., 0.0, 0.0]] | [[0.00005, ..., 0.0003]] | [23, 4, 6, 11, ..., 12 |
| audio2.mp3 | This is the second audio | [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ..., 0.0, 0.0]] | [[0.000044, ..., 0.00033]] | [23, 4, 6, 11, ..., 12 |

The sentence is the transcription of the audio, the speech column is the array representation of the audio, and labels is the number representation of the each letter of the sentence based on a defined vocab list.

I'm fine-tuning a pre-trained ASR model, but when I try to pass the pandas df to the Trainer class and call `.train()` on it, it errors out (KeyError: 0). From the documentation, it only accepts `torch.utils.data.Dataset` or `torch.utils.data.IterableDataset` as train_/eval_dataset arguments. This is how my Trainer definition looks like:

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    args=training_args,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    train_dataset=ds_train, 
    eval_dataset=ds_test,
    tokenizer=processor.feature_extractor
)
```

ds_train and ds_test are my training and validation dataframes respectively. I just split my main dataframe (80/20). How can I convert my pandas dataframes into the required Dataset type? I tried tailoring the `data_collator` class definition to a pandas df but that predictably didn't work either. I'm assuming the train and eval datasets both call the `data_collator` class when you call `.train()` on the trainer?

**EDIT**: I tried using `Dataset.from_pandas(ds_train)` but it couldn't convert it because I had columns with two-dimensional arrays and it can apparently only convert one-dimensional array values.

Comment: what's a `ds_train` here exactly? Your dataframe?

Comment: Yes, my training dataframe; similarly for ds_test (validation dataset). I tried using them as inputs before learning it only accepted torch datasets, which is why I want to convert them (if that's even the solution here).

Comment: I tried using `Dataset.from_pandas(ds_train)` but it couldn't convert it because I had columns with two-dimensional arrays and it can apparently only convert one-dimensional array values.

Comment: `Dataset.from_pandas` ? I cannot see such function in API, could you point me to it?

Comment: This is what I meant: https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/loading_datasets.html#from-a-pandas-dataframe but looking at it again, it isn't a torch Dataset, but I'm pretty sure it's the same type used for Common Voice datasets which work as input to the trainer. I'm following this tutorial: https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-xlsr-wav2vec2 but my dataset is different; I don't use Common Voice.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you will use your `labels` column.
I don't know how your your trainer use these data but I suggest to define your own Dataset class (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html#creating-a-custom-dataset-for-your-files)

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.path = dataframe["path"]
        self.sentence = dataframe["sentence"]
        self.speech = dataframe["speech"]
        self.input_values = dataframe["input_values"]
        self.labels = dataframe["labels"]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.text)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        path = self.path.iloc[idx]
        sentence = self.sentence.iloc[idx]
        speech = self.speech.iloc[idx]
        input_values = self.input_values .iloc[idx]
        labels = self.labels.iloc[idx]
        return path, sentence, speech, input_values, labels
```